# different dispatcher for the same actor

Tags: scala, akka

Looking at my log file I see different dispatcher for the same actor. that actor is created once so how can it be ? is that means that the actor was restarted due to crash ?
e.g :

> [ERROR] [08/07/2017 19:20:22.618]
>   [my-sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21]
>   [akka://my-sys/user/com.domain.FooActor] some_exception
>
> [ERROR] [08/07/2017 19:20:22.619]
>   [my-sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-26]
>   [akka://my-sys/user/com.domain.FooActor] some_exception
>
> [ERROR] [08/07/2017 19:20:22.619]
>   [my-sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-27]
>   [akka://my-sys/user/com.domain.FooActor] some_exception

Comment: Couldn't those just be different threads of the default dispatcher?

Comment: Yes it is. Can be easily checked by having a look at the logging conf.

Comment: @FredericA. the actor is created once. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @cchantep can you please elaborate ? do you mean it is restarted ?

Comment: Your logging is configured to display the context thread, not meaning in anyway that the `Actor` itself is managed by multiple dispatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your logger is configured to log the thread from which the log was generated. Check your logger config, but I guess that the at the third position, you log the thread (thread names from the log above: `my-sys-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-XX`).

A dispatcher will schedule your tasks to run on a pool of threads. By definition a pool can have multiple threads, and through the logs, you see that your actor's execution is schedule on different threads belonging to a single dispatcher.

With the given logs, there's no clear indication that your actor crashed/got restarted, just indication that it (or its supervisor) called log methods (i.e., `log.error()`) while running on different threads. This is expected as multiple (potentially millions) actors are meant to share a few threads (in the case of the default dispatcher depends on the number of CPU, cores, ...).

You should not expect your actors to always run on the same thread.

There's no way an actor gets to run on another dispatcher (unless you explicitly configure it that way).